# How to add and center an icon in a button?

Tags: html, css

Im having issues while trying to center my icon on the button, here is the code and the print

[image: button]

edit: here the html code too

obs: this .btn code is just me trying to center the button, without succes,

```
 <button class="btn">
     <i class="gg-format-justify"> </i>
 </button>


.btn
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    /*border: none; */
    cursor: pointer;
  
}


    .gg-format-justify,
    .gg-format-justify::before {
     display: block;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     width: 16px;
     height: 2px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     background: currentColor;
     box-shadow: 0 8px 0;
     color: rgb(47, 94, 183);
    }

.gg-format-justify {
     margin-top: -11px;
     transform: scale(var(--ggs,1));
     position: relative
    }
    
    .gg-format-justify::before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: 4px;
     left: 0
    }
```

Comment: Is that blue transparent box on the picture your button? or do you want to center that box under the 4 horizontal lines?

Comment: yesss, thats the buttom, i didnt remove the border yet so  the issue  could be visible

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @caiopcabral can you provide us with the HTML? ` <button type="button">YourIconHere</button> ` Have you tried this?

Comment: <button class="btn">
        <i class="gg-format-justify"> </i>
  </button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get bars (and icons) easier using font awesome:
put this in your head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Put this in your body

```
<button class="btn"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </button>
```

Put this in your style like Connor mentioned:

```
.btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

This should get you bars in the center, for more icons:
https://fontawesome.com/search?s=solid&f=sharp&o=r

Comment: yep this worked, i was using another site for the icons but i'll use this one for now, thanks u helped me a lot, now its time to do the rest of my portfolium , thanksss

Comment: @caiopcabral next time please use the site https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp this site provides you with the basic information you need for your portfolio. (:

Answer (score 0):

Would be be helpful if you can provide the HTML as well. But you can try
using flexbox to centre elements. This would essentially centre the button within its container

```
    .btn {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      width: 16px;
      height: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

If you want read a good resource you can check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Comment: thx for the help, but it didnt worked, still not centralized and now my icon is desfigurized, btw i put the html code in the question now